# Stack Exchange Privacy Policy Revision history

Tags: discussion, feature-request, policy, privacy

On https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy, there is mention that "If we change this policy, we’ll update this document to keep you in the loop".. Great!

However, I have never liked re-reading changes to policies, trying to pick what was changed. Think it would be great if this page had revision history like the Network's answers so one can see at a glance what change(s) have been made. What does the community think?

Comment: Every privacy policy in the world should have this feature.