# How come some posts lack 'active' hyperlink?

Tags: support, user-interface, last-activity

Some posts don't have a link on the right (named `active`) that would take me to the latest edited post on a thread. What are the criteria?

- [example *with* `active` link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915)
- [example *without* `active` link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161771)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `active` tells you when a question was 'last active', and links to what activity there was most recently.

One of the answers for that question, *or* the question itself was edited, or a new answer was added; the link leads to the post that was last updated or added. It is only shown if there is at least one answer; it is not shown on questions without an answer.

In the first example, at the time of this answer, the active link points to a new answer added 2 months ago; no other new answers or edits were made since then. The second example you give has had no answer, so no link is shown.